# Are there any Cryptography Algorithms that involve Lots of Number Theory?

Tags: encryption, rsa, aes, cryptanalysis

I am looking for a good, meaty cryptography algorithm that involves a good amount of number theory in which I can explore. I'm researching, and AES (Advanced Encryption System) seems interesting, but does not really seem to involve number theory all that much.

EDIT: Not RSA.

Comment: You may want to check out our help center on how open-ended and opinion-based questions should be avoided. Then, you can edit your question to be more focused, because we want to make sure a large majority of questions can be useful to at least multiple people.

Comment: Elliptic Curves are also based on number (or rather group-) theory.

Answer (score 4):

The [Falcon digital signature algorithm](http://falcon-sign.info/) is as "meaty" as one can be.

- It has an NTRU-like key generation procedure and public key lattice structure;
- its security is based on conjectured difficulty of lattice reduction in classical and quantum computers;
- its efficiency is based on number-theoretic transformation and fast discrete normal distribution sampling;
- its compactness is based on entropy coding.

Some more to be listed.

Comment: "Some more to be listed."? Those are quite a few good reasons though. And note that Falcon is a 3rd level candidate for the PQC competition by NIST. It might not make it, but studying Post Quantum lattice based cryptosystems is certainly a good idea.